# Tablix Cells with Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I have a RDLC report like below,

I want `Date,Name,GSTIN,Grams,Amount,CGST,SGST` fields to RDLC with Date DESC order with multiple table

[image]

It allows me to only show record from one table (ex:tbl_stock_gold)

But I want to show from Three Tables (ie: tbl_stock_gold,tbl_stock_copper,tbl_stock_stone) like below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query it helps to get help

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I think you are asking how to write a `SELECT` query using three tables. However you have not explained what relationship the tables have. If they are three separate commodities and can be merged in queries as one big table, then you can use a `UNION`.

Comment: Hi halfer, you exactly understands my question. So I want the query to me the table and list down in rdlc report..